# Java AWS S3 SDK2 how to perform async bulk operations

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I'd like to perform bulk operations within S3 asynchronously. For some reason, I could not find a way of doing that in the new SDK2 client built by AWS. I currently use the [S3AsyncClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3AsyncClient.html)'s `putObject` method for uploading files, but I'd like to do that in batches for performance improvements. The same applies to downloading files. I've read about multipart uploads but I did not understand if that's what I'm looking for, since my files are relatively small and I don't need a multipart upload. I How can I perform a multi-file upload?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`S3TransferManager`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/S3TransferManager.html) which is the implementation of [`TransferManager`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) library [adjusted for AWS Java SDK v2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-amazon-s3-transfer-manager-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-2-x/). `S3TransferManager` provides bulk uploads by using multiple threads.

Keep in mind that in case of S3 you are paying for each `PUT` request. Each file upload will constitute at least one PUT request. Even if you are using something like `uploadDirectory` from the `S3TransferManager`, you will still pay for after each file.

Comment: But will the performance still get improved? Will there be one request under the hood or multiple requests?

Comment: And also, in my case there is no directories. Will I still be able to perform batch operations for the files?

Comment: "But will the performance still get improved?" From the AWS docs: "Using Transfer Manager’s simple API, you can now perform accelerated uploads and downloads of objects to and from Amazon S3 and benefit from enhanced throughput and reliability, which is achieved through concurrent transfers of a set of small parts from a single object."

Comment: Now, if you really care about performance, you should do some actual measurements at least to have baseline for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a multi-file upload mode in Amazon S3.

Another way is to **zip** the files and upload one big file, where you will benefit from multipart uploads. Then you let a **Lambda function**, triggered by the upload of a zip in your bucket, **unzip automatically** the files for you.

Further description of alternatives and a code example for the zip & unzip strategy can be found [here](https://princekfrancis.medium.com/multiple-file-upload-into-amazon-s3-bucket-9888d51001bb).